# pretty-printing malformed xml

Tags: xml, pretty-print

I am working on a data migration and I am parsing and exporting html into xml. The html gets escaped, of course, when it goes into the xml, but to verify that parsing is happening properly, I am decoding the brackets to get readable html tags inside the xml. However, the tags are all run-together, and it's still not very readable.

Is there something that can simply indent the tag structure that I have? It's neither valid xml nor html. I've tried `xmllint --format` and `xmllint --htmlout`, but both of those choke at different points.

Can I avoid doing this by hand?

Here is a small example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<result><node><title>This would be the title</title><uri>/path/filename.jpg</uri><alt>Alt tag data</alt><body><p>Some text goes here.</body></node></result>
```

In the actual data, the html tags inside `<body>` are all escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but that was too difficult to eyeball to see if the parsing worked correctly. So I changed them to their bracket equivalents with a find and replace. But they are still not indented, so it is difficult to read.

Both `tidy` and `xmllint` complain about the missing closing `<p>` tag. In this data, there are a number of missing or mis-matched tags. I understand that this is not valid html or xml, but the cleanup of the html we'll do later, at this point I just have to make sure that the html is getting parsed at the right places, which is difficult to see when there are no line breaks or indentation.

To fix the above example, I could remove or close the `<p>` tag manually, but in the actual data, there is a lot of brokenness, and it would be a non-trivial task to fix tags just to get it to parse for formatting. At this phase I am trying to avoid manual massaging and do things in an automated manner.

For example, for this one file, tidy reports 65 warnings and 778 errors. Fixing them all by hand would be a waste of time -- I might as well start indenting myself. I need something that can indent in a non-strict manner, and is not going to care about unmatched tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the formatting function that user [Josh Leitzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86937/josh-leitzel) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746443/151841). Not perfect, but good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [tidy](/questions/tagged/tidy) :

```
$ tidy -h
tidy [option...] [file...] [option...] [file...]
Utility to clean up and pretty print HTML/XHTML/XML
```

See http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

### Edit

Your problem is just the `<p>` tag, you should remove it :

```
$ xmllint --format file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<result>
  <node>
    <title>This would be the title</title>
    <uri>/path/filename.jpg</uri>
    <alt>Alt tag data</alt>
    <body>Some text goes here.</body>
  </node>
</result>
```

No error.

### Edit 2

My thought is to use a tool like `html2text` to feed the xml with no html tags, and maybe you can store the indentation of HTML files in XML CTAGS

Comment: The starting tag is `<result>` and `tidy -i` chokes right away on it :P

Comment: You should consider add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` to the file

Comment: I tried that and it still dislikes the `<result>` tag (amongst other things) -- is there a different switch I should use?

Comment: I cannot help more without viewing the source XML

Comment: That would be better to indent it properly.

Comment: This example is just a small part of the mass of data I'm dealing with. I am trying to avoid editing it by hand so going in and removing tags defeats a lot of the purpose. There are much more eggregious problems than a missing closing tag, and it would take a lot of work to fix tags just to get them to parse properly, when we are going to end up throwing out the tags later. We know we are dealing with broken html and part of this migration is so that we don't waste time fixing it. I don't want to do anything by hand at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too recently and wrote my own in Python (3) using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.6.0) (v4 +) with some extra wrapping of long lines provided by `textwrap.wrap()`:

```
   import sys
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   from textwrap import wrap

   path = f'{sys.argv[1]}'

   with open(path) as fp:
       for line in wrap(BeautifulSoup(fp).prettify(), replace_whitespace=False):
           print(line)
```

BeutifySoup does a good job at promiscuously interpret most tag-based junk you throw at it. No indentation of tags with this solution, though.